# How to match regex only if it starts with the user input?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am making a search bar, which shows whether a brand is Indian or foreign. The results are fetched from a JSON file (using the fetch API).
This is the code snippet -

```js
const matchList = document.querySelector('#match-list');

//searching data.json and filter it
const searchBrand = async searchText => {
  const res = await fetch('https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5f3e87fd4d93991036190251');
  const brands = await res.json();

  // get matches to current text input
  let matches = brands.filter(brand => {
    const regex = new RegExp(searchText, 'gi');

    return brand.name.match(regex);
  });

  if (searchText.length === 0) {
    matches = [];
    matchList.innerHTML = '';
  }

  outputHTML(matches);
};

//Show HTML
const outputHTML = matches => {
  if (matches.length > 0) {
    const html = matches
      .map(match => {
        if (match.country === 'foreign') {
          return `
            <div class="card card-body mb-4">
            <h5><span class="text-primary">${match.name}</span> <span class="text-danger">(${match.country})</span></h5>
            <big>category: ${match.category}</big>
            </div>
          `;
        } else {
          return `
            <div class="card card-body mb-4">
            <h5><span class="text-primary">${match.name}</span> <span class="text-success">(${match.country})</span></h5>
            <big>category: ${match.category}</big>
            </div>
          `;
        }
      })
      .join('');
    matchList.innerHTML = html;
  }
};

const search = document.querySelector('#search');

search.addEventListener('input', () => {
  searchBrand(search.value);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Which Country ?</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 m-auto">
        <h2 class="text-center mb-3">
          Which Country ?
        </h2>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="search" placeholder="Enter brand name..." />
        </div>
        <div id="match-list"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem is that when user inputs a valid brand name, then the correct brand is displayed, but when the user inputs extra characters after a brand name, it still shows the brands..
For example, when I enter "col", then brands starting from "col" are displayed. This is as expected. When the user enters "colgate", then information about colgate is displayed, this is again expected..But when the input is "colgatxsaf2e", then also "colgate" is the result. I want it to stop showing any results when the input is an invalid brand name.

Sorry it this seems confusing, please ask in the comments and feel free to edit.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `^` in regex to match string start.

`const regex = new RegExp('^' + searchText, 'gi');`

Comment: thank you. It definitely was a problem, but the main problem what in DOM painting. When the user inputs does not match any brand name, then I had to clear the DOM, which I forgot to do. That's why older results were still showing. Thanks again